# Tagged Object Not Work In CakePHP 2.5.1 Tag Plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, tags, cakephp-2.0

I just found issue about finding tagged object relation with Tag Plugin of CakePHP 2.5.1. 
I was read the tutorial in:

https://github.com/CakeDC/tags/blob/master/Docs/Tutorials/Find-Tagged-Objects.md

Then create in my Controller:

```
if (isset($this->passedArgs['by'])) {
        if(ctype_alnum($this->passedArgs['by'])) {
            $this->paginate['Tagged'] = array(
                'tagged',
                'model' => 'Story',
                'by' => $this->passedArgs['by']);
            $rows = $this->paginate( 'Tagged' );
        }                
    } else {
        $this->Story->recursive = 1;
        $rows = $this->paginate();
    }
```

But, why i only get Tagged text in browser as result of $rows?

[image]

If i try to change $rows = $this->paginate( 'Tagged' ); to $rows = $this->paginate( 'Story' );, query is work, by seems like no effect of find by tag params.

Someone please help me.